# joomla html module overriding doesn't work

Tags: php, joomla

My structure of overriding is:

```
template_name/html/mod_menu/tmpl/default.php
```

but joomla are still getting the core template, instead of this, why this happening?

also maybe this error relates somehow:

```
Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/targetcode/domains/powergeek.ru/public_html/test/templates/temgaz/css/index.html/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/targetcode/domains/powergeek.ru/:/home/targetcode/phptmp/:/tmp:/usr/local/php5/lib/php) in /home/targetcode/domains/powergeek.ru/public_html/test/administrator/components/com_templates/models/template.php on line 111
```

joomla version 3.2(last stable)

and yes:

```
public $log_path = '/home/public_html/test/logs';
public $tmp_path = '/home/public_html/test/tmp';
```

I've writed the log and tmp vars to avoid that errors, but didn't helped

I see this in the template page, any ideas???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating template overrides, you *don't* use the **tmpl** folder. Move your **default.php** back 1 folder. So it will look like this:

```
template_name/html/mod_menu/default.php
```

Hope this helps